# Structure of a Serialized PHP string

Tags: php, string, serialization

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a resource where the details of a serialized php string is documented. I would basically like to know the format/structure so I can write a function in VB.NET to serialize/deserialize it back.

Thanks!

Comment: Use JSON instead (`echo json_encode($arr);`). The PHP native serializer is weird, in my opinion, and JSON is heavily supported and easier to work with. [VB JSON parser class.](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html)

Comment: @JaredF An unhelpful comment as the questioner doesn't specify a use-case that indicates a change in format would be possible or even desirable.  JSON is wholly orthogonal to the question being asked.  In addition, there are many use-cases for which JSON is an inappropriate serialisation format, e.g. if there is recursion or if the ordering of array keys matters.  JSON should not be considered a default go-to format without understanding these restrictions.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The basic structure is as follows:

**Scalar types:**

1. Booleans are serialized as:

   ```
   b:<i>;
   ```

   where `<i>` is an integer with a value of either `0` (false) or `1` (true).
2. Integers are serialized as:

   ```
   i:<i>;
   ```

   where `<i>` is the integer value.
3. Floats are serialized as (with `d` meaning double):

   ```
   d:<f>;
   ```

   where `<f>` is the float value.
4. Strings are serialized as:

   ```
   s:<i>:"<s>";
   ```

   where `<i>` is an integer representing the string length of `<s>`, and `<s>` is the string value.

**Special types:**

1. `null` is simply serialized as:

   ```
   N;
   ```

**Compound types:**

1. Arrays are serialized as:

   ```
   a:<i>:{<elements>}
   ```

   where `<i>` is an integer representing the number of elements in the array, and `<elements>` zero or more serialized key value pairs:

   ```
   <key><value>
   ```

   where `<key>` represents a serialized scalar type, and `<value>` any value that is serializable.
2. Objects are serialized as:

   ```
   O:<i>:"<s>":<i>:{<properties>}
   ```

   where the first `<i>` is an integer representing the string length of `<s>`, and `<s>` is the fully qualified class name (class name prepended with full namespace). The second `<i>` is an integer representing the number of object properties. `<properties>` are zero or more serialized name value pairs:

   ```
   <name><value>
   ```

   where `<name>` is a serialized string representing the property name, and `<value>` any value that is serializable.

   **There's a catch with `<name>` though:**

   `<name>` is represented as

   ```
   s:<i>:"<s>";
   ```

   where `<i>` is an integer representing the string length of `<s>`. But the values of `<s>` differs per visibility of properties:

   a. With **public** properties `<s>` is the simple name of the property.

   b. With **protected** properties, however, `<s>` is the simple name of the property, prepended with `\0*\0` — an asterix, enclosed in two `NUL` characters (i.e. `chr(0)`).

   c. And with **private** properties, `<s>` is the simple name of the property, prepended with `\0<s>\0` — `<s>`, enclosed in two `NUL` characters, where `<s>` is the fully qualified class name.

---

There are a few other cases, such as `R:<i>;`, that represents references, that I haven't mentioned here (because I honestly haven't figured out the exact workings of it yet), but this should give you a decent idea about PHP's serializing mechanism.

Comment: Nice info about the _public_ and _protected_ properties names! I couldn't find it in the PHP serialize documentation.

Comment: @Danogentili Thank you for the suggested edit. Looks good. However before approving it, could you perhaps provide a test case for the uppercase R scenario? I haven't been able to reproduce that in PHP 5.5.9. Is this PHP 5.6 or PHP 7 behavior, perhaps? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can reproduce this even on PHP 4.4.9: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdb72b06c99e525b2bf4627ced0a0973bc3c3191

Comment: Missing information: how some special characters in strings are escaped (and in particular double quotes).

Answer (score 13):

I've found [this page at phpinternalsbook](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/classes_objects/serialization.html) quite complete. It also shows the alternative serialization format for classes implementing `Serializable` interface, as well as the meaning of `R` format specifier.