# combine two serialize data in php

Tags: php, serialization, deserialization

```
$var1='a:1:{i:123;s:3:"123";}';

$var2='a:1:{i:56;s:2:"56";}';

output a:2:{i:56;s:2:"56";i:123;s:3:"123";}
```

Without changing the value of i

Example2;

```
$var1='a:2:{i:56;s:2:"56";i:123;s:3:"123";}';

$var2='a:1:{i:154;s:3:"154";}';

ouput a:3:{i:56;s:2:"56";i:123;s:3:"123";i:154;s:3:"154";}
```

i am using

```
$a=unserialize($var1); 
$a2=unserialize($var2); 
$result = array_merge($a, $a2); 
$serialized_array=serialize($result); 
print_r($serialized_array);
```

but all the values of i got changed

also what does `s` stands for in above strings

Comment: Unserialize them, combine them however you want, then serialize that.

Comment: `i` stands for `integer`, `s` stands for `string`.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this? If so, why are you judging anything by its serialized output, rather than just specifying the array you want.

Comment: And `a` stands for `array`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string to understand the parts of a serialized string.

Comment: @Barmar They're right aren't they? Arrays are serialized as `a:count:{key;value}`

Comment: @Barmar can you please provide me the code how to do that, i am using $a=unserialize($var1);
$a2=unserialize($var2); $result = array_merge($a, $a2); $serialized_array=serialize($result);
print_r($serialized_array); but all the values of i got changed

Answer (score 2):

Unserialize them, concatenate the arrays, then serialize that.

```
echo serialize(unserialize($var1) + unserialize($var2));
```

You have to use `+` instead of `array_merge()` because the latter re-indexes the array if the keys are all integers. Since all your keys begin with `i:`, that means they're numeric indexes.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/qEi0pV)

For the meaning of `s`, see [Structure of a Serialized PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string)

Comment: a:2:{i:0;s:3:"123";i:1;s:2:"56";}  as you can see the i:0 and i:1 but is should be same  like a:2:{i:123;s:3:"123";i:56;s:2:"56";}  (i:123 and i:56)

Comment: `array_merge` reindexes the arrays if the keys are numbers rather than strings. That's why we use `+` in the answers.

Comment: one last thing please help $var1='a:1:{i:4;i:4;}'; $var2='a:1:{i:3;s:1:"3";}'; output = a:2:{i:3;s:1:"3"; i:4;s:1:"4";} as you can see it add s:1 to $var1. how can i do that –

Comment: $tournament_candidate='a:1:{i:4;i:4;}' and $tournament_competitors='a:1:{i:3;s:1:"3";}'; after union it should be like this a:2:{i:3;s:1:"3"; i:4;s:1:"4";}

Comment: Why is the value a number instead of a string in the first array?

Comment: After unserializing, you can use a `foreach` loop to replace numbers with strings.

Comment: But most of the time PHP doesn't care, it will automatically convert between numbers and strings as needed.

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of serialized data, and work with the original arrays.

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_merge` will re-index arrays with numeric keys. If you want to avoid this, you can use the array union operator (`+`) instead:

```
$combined = unserialize($var2) + unserialize($var1);
```

This will give you the correct serialized output.

See https://eval.in/894864 to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: one last thing please help $var1='a:1:{i:4;i:4;}'; $var2='a:1:{i:3;s:1:"3";}'; output = a:2:{i:3;s:1:"3"; i:4;s:1:"4";}   as you can see it add s:1 to $var1. how can i do that