# Structure of a field in the wp_options table in the Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I was checking the wp_options table in the Wordpress database, and I found the following code in the option_value column:

```
a:3:{s:5:"title";s:43:"Entrega entre 1-2 días hábiles";s:10:"tax_status";s:4:"none";s:4:"cost";s:4:"11000";}
```

I know that this line is for shipping methods. My question is what represents or what the value is: 43
[image]

Comment: I'll fund the duplicate, but you are seeing [serialized data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).  If you use the proper WP function, such as [get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_option/), OR if you're accessing the data raw, simply use PHP's [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), you won't need to deal with those aspects :)

Comment: Also - to answer your _specific_ question - `s:43` means "string, 43 characters in length".  This answer explains those bits in more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string