# How to match specific pattern with regex in a serialised string

Tags: php, regex

I have something like this

```
a:2:{s:4:"Test";s:29:"asdf'a\' ;"serialize here;?"!";s:5:"test2";a:1:{s:4:"Test";s:15:"serialize here!";}}
```

and I want to make a regex in order to match both examples below:

```
s:15:"serialize

s:29:"asdf'a\' ;"serialize
```

How can I do that?

I tried something like `s:\d+:".+?serialize`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not unserialize it and work with that?

Comment: Your regexp works for me: https://ideone.com/9URK80

Comment: @Barmar because thats an example, the real data are more complex and too large to unserialize and serialize

Comment: Please provide an example that shows the problem.

Comment: also when i use the regex that i made it gives me `s:4:"Test";s:29:"asdf'a\' ;"serialize` but i want `s:29:"asdf'a\' ;"serialize`

Comment: This is not something that's easy to do with regexp. You don't want it to match across other `s:<something>`, but a regexp can't tell the difference between that inside a string and outside a string.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex and not [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) the data first? See this page for [Structure of a Serialized PHP string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297926/structure-of-a-serialized-php-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
\bs:\d+:"(?:(?!\bs:\d).)*?serialize
```

A couple notes regarding you attempt:

- `s:\d+` would also match something like "likes:123". To avoid this I added `\b`,
- `.+?` matches at least one symbol, and in your example one of the expected outputs has zero. Also, lazy modifier works only for the right side of matching: this is the reason it matched form the first `s:\d+` till the `serialize` and not nearest pair.

To match closes pair of `s:\d+` and `serialize` I'm using `(?:(?!\bs:\d).)*?`. It matches smallest possible block, that doesn't contain `s:\d` in between.

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/J8sH21/2).

Comment: `(?!\bs:\d+)`: an unfixed quantifier at the end of a lookahead is always useless. `(?!\bs:\d)` does the same.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, fair point. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following.

Granted, there must be no colon, :, between the *s:\d:* and *"serialize"*.

```
s:\d+:[^:]+serialize
```

Matches

```
s:29:"asdf'a\' ;"serialize
s:15:"serialize
```

Comment: Yes unfortunately sometimes the colon also exists as part of the string... I don't think I can use any specific character, only a compilation of characters like 's:' ...... but when I try this it doesn't work as expected s:\d+:[^(s:)]+serialize

Comment: @christsironis, so, the colon would be within two double quotation marks?  Additionally, can the text contain a double quotation mark if it is escaped?  For example, _s:29:"asdf'a\' : \"example\" ;"serialize_.